# heroku clearing git logs and start afresh

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I had a heroku app. I cloned it started working on it. There were some issues and accidentally i deleted the .git directory locally and initialized a new directory using `git init`.

After that i made several commits and added several features to my code. Now what I want to push the code to the heroku dyno.

So I do git remote add origin `git-remote-url`. 
Tried `git push` but got error, doing a `git pull` gives the following error -

```
warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-887ccc7bf1196e49089e449ae1edd93c87c785b8.pack cannot be accessed
fatal: bad object 00eb66f14b52f3808720aaa35285a4f32e019a05
error: heroku.com:******.git did not send all necessary objects
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is linked to the state of your current repo (the one you `git init` again), which doesn't contain the full history already published.
You would need to clone again your heroku reop, in order to apply the new commit you did in your local (but incomplete) repo;

Something like:

```
git clone --bare yourHerokuRepo
cd /path/to/myapp                                       # where you deleted the `.git`)
git remote add localHeroku /path/to/yourHerokuRepo.git
git branch -m master oldmaster                          # where your new commits are
git fetch localHeroku                                   # get the full history
git checkout -b master localHeroku/master               # now working on the branch with
                                                        # a full history
git cherry-pick ..oldmaster                             # re-apply all your commits
git push
```